How to make a lesson of mathematical aggregation in Latex?
I am trying to make a page similar to this one (le plan d'une leçon d'agrégation) in Latex but in vain ! If any one can help please !
This is my code :
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\hline 
\vline 
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
  \textbf{ Thm 1 :}  \lipsum[1] % Content for the left half of the page
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\vline 
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
    \lipsum[2] % Content for the right half of the page
\end{minipage}
\hline 
\vline
\end{document}



Quite unreadable. However, it doesn’t seem to have too many difficulties from a Latex perspective. What code did you try?

I need just a rectangular page divided in two as in the picture and inside of it my theorems !

I have edited the question !

As you will probably experience soon, the „currency“ here is: code ;-)

To elaborate a bit, on this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a minimal working example (MWE): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Thank you ! I have edited my answer !

You can maybe try a tcolorbox with the key side by side.

You can use the multicol package to divide the page into two (or more) equal parts. And choose the landscape option for the document class, which will orient the page in landscape position (and not portrait).

You can use the landscape, twocolumn and showframe options of the geometry package.
Add some tinkering to the geometry of the page and it should work without necessitating any other package.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[landscape,twocolumn,showframe]{geometry} 


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
\hoffset=-7truemm
\evensidemargin=-10truemm
\oddsidemargin=-10truemm
\textwidth=280truemm
\textheight=200truemm
\marginparwidth=0truemm
\marginparsep=0truemm
\topmargin=-10truemm
\voffset=-10truemm
\headheight=0truemm
\headsep=0truemm
\paperheight=210truemm
\paperwidth=297truemm

%%%% Central vertical line
\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{.1pt}



\begin{document}

\textbf{ Thm 1 :}  \lipsum[1] % Content for the left half of the page

\newpage

\lipsum[2] % Content for the right half of the page

\end{document}



Like they recommended you, the package tcolorbox is useful to this with side by side: 
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,landscape]{article}
    \usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage[a4paper,margin=1cm]{geometry}
    
    \begin{document}
    \tcbset{colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,fonttitle=\bfseries,nobeforeafter,left=2mm,right=2mm,sidebyside,sidebyside gap=6mm,width=(\linewidth-2mm)/3}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[adjusted title = {Lesson $\pi$},width=\textwidth,sidebyside align=top]
    \lipsum[1-3]
    \tcblower
    \lipsum[4-7]
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}

you can change the back color with colback=namecolor and the frame with colframe inside the option of tcolorbox environment.
